# In Java, I'm trying to for an empty value from a ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, server, client, registration

```
private boolean checkingDataBase(String email) {
    String query = String.format("SELECT email FROM users where email = '%s'", email);
    try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)) {
        String s = "";
        if (rs.getString("email").isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("true");
            return true;    
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("faaalse");
            return false;
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } return false;
}
```

I think, I'm doing everything wrong. Can anyone show a way how to make it right

Comment: Did you try debugging to see what value does `rs` have ?

Comment: There's missed `rs.next()`
see example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html

Comment: The only way that could possibly work is if `email` is `""` and there is actually such a record. This code is vulnerable to sql injection, and your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: Your question makes no sense at all. Suppose if `email` in the query is itself empty and using that email you're trying to query to get email again ???

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? Please select one option: 1) No rows are returned, 2) The returned value is an empty string, 3) The returned value is NULL.